# BPEL Visual Designer Eclipse not well installed

Tags: eclipse, bpel, ode

This is the steps i followed to install BPEL Visual Designer into Eclipse Indigo 3.7.2....:

1. Suppose that you have already downloaded and installed your Eclipse

   > v3.6.2(Helios,or Indigo), version for Java EE Developers and JDK (version > 1.5).
2. Open the Eclipse, go to the menu Help→Install New
   SoftWare.
3. Click on the button Add and define a new Eclipe update
   site with the location:  http://download.eclipse.org/bpel/site/
4. Now you have the update-site of BPEL available on the eclipse. Select
   the check box to BPEL Visual Designer and click on the button Next.

But when i restart Eclipse that the changes takes effect i don't find BPEL installed ==> no BPEL project when trying to create a new project.

Any ideas ?

The snapshot of the wizard after using the Eclipse Helios from WS02.

[image]

The snapshots of the Installation Details in Eclipse Helios from WS02.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's not working not even with Eclipse Helios or Juno, eventhought if there is no error while installing the BPEL packages from http://download.eclipse.org/bpel/site/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mansour, I tried to install Eclipse `BPEL` editor on a fresh eclipse pack `(eclipse-jee-indigo-SR2-linux-gtk-x86_64)`. But I was able to install it successfully and able to created a sample project.

I recommended to use `Helios`, not `Juno` because there are some known issues with `Juno` and `BPEL` designer.

If problem still exist, you can use [WSO2 Developer studio](http://wso2.org/more-downloads/developer-studio/3.0.0) as an alternative. It has a fork version of eclipse BPEL designer with some more features.( `E4X` assign, `humantask` support etc.).

Comment: I downloaded the "Eclipse JavaEE Helios + Developer Studio v3.0.0" for Windows 64bit from the Url you suggested http://wso2.org/more-downloads/developer-studio/3.0.0 it doesn't work, i don't see the BPEL project in the Eclipse Wizard. For information, i'm using JDK 1.5 Update 22 in Windows 7 64Bit.

Comment: could you tell me what are the available options in new project wizard ? ( File -> New -> Project ) . Normally BPEL project is located under BPEL 2.0 category.

Comment: I added the snapshot of the wizard after using the Eclipse Helios from WS02. i used both a 32Bit and 64Bit version, i always get the same problem; There is no BPEL 2.0 as i supposed to have.

Comment: seems like BPEL editor feature is installed. But it is not visible in new project wizard. So it can be a problem with your environment. Could you upgrade your JAVA version to 1.6 and test ?

Comment: Effectively, it needed JDK 1.6, it is not compatible with JDK 1.5. I didn't see that (JDK (version > 1.5)).Thank you very much Hasitha.

Comment: Just for anyone who want to install BPEL plugin: the update site is : http://download.eclipse.org/bpel/site/. The site http://download.eclipse.org/technology/bpel/update-site/ is no longer working.